# AzureKeyCredential for Search via identity.DefaultAzureCredential

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a console that is logged into Azure via `az login`

I can run the follow JavaScript and the console outputs my details as I would expect

```
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
console.log(credential);
```

Using the `credential`s I would like to read the API key from a `Search service`

So, I can then use the `apiKey` as follows

```
indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(searchURL, new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));
```

Comment: What's the question here? Please provide us with information like what you have tried and why that didn't work. In its current form, this question is no fit for SO. Please refer to [ask]. Do I understand correctly that you want to read the Search API key using Managed Identity so you can use it to connect with Azure search?

Comment: @rickvdbosch thanks for the feedback, and yes you have understood my Q' I am dyslexic and although I do re-read my posts often they don't make as much sense as I would hope and reading a how to ask guide is also a little difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using the credentials I would like to read the API key from a Search
> service

To get the admin keys, you will need to use a separate SDK: [@azure/arm-search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/arm-search/?view=azure-node-latest). Once you have created a [`SearchManagementClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/arm-search/searchmanagementclient?view=azure-node-latest) using that SDK and AzureCredentials, you will need to invoke one of the `get` methods for [`AdminKeys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/arm-search/adminkeys?view=azure-node-latest).

Comment: thanks, I now get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unexpected end of JSON input` when i call `await searchMan.adminKeys.get` but I am sure I will sort that.. thanks for a quick reply.

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to post another question if you're not able to sort it out. Good luck!

Comment: I sorted it, thanks